# Jquery dependent dropdown clone not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic dependent dropdown of Country state and city.When it is not cloned working fine but when clone not working.

```js
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(function(){
        $(".addButton").click(function(){
 
            $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo(".Delivery");
  

  
        });

        $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
  
            if ($("table tr").length != 2) {
         $("table tr:last").remove();
    }
  
        });
    });

     load_json_data('country');

     function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
     {
     var data_id = $('#data_ids').val();
      var html_code = '';
      $.getJSON('country_state_city.json', function(data){

       html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
       $.each(data, function(key, value){
        if(id == 'country')
        {
         if(value.parent_id == '0')
         {
          html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
         }
        }
        else
        {
         if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
         {
          html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
         }
        }
       });
       $('.'+id).html(html_code);
      });

     }

     $(document).on('change', '.country', function(){
      var country_id = $(this).val();
      if(country_id != '')
      {
       load_json_data('state', country_id);
      }
      else
      {
       $('.state').html('<option value="">Select state</option>');
       $('.city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
      }
     });
     $(document).on('change', '.state', function(){
      var state_id = $(this).val();
      if(state_id != '')
      {
       load_json_data('city', state_id);
      }
      else
      {
       $('.city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
  
      <script src="https:ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <script src="https:maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
    </br></br>
  
         <form method="post" action="RGAForm.php">

                <table class="Delivery">
                   <tr>
                      <th>Country Name</th>
                      <th>State Name</th>
                      <th>City Name</th>
      </tr>
    <tr>

       <td>
      <select name="country"  class="form-control input-lg country" id="country_1 data-id="1">
       <option value="">Select country</option>
      </select>
       </td>
                      <td>
       <select name="state" class="form-control input-lg state"  id="state_1" data-id="1">
        <option value="">Select state</option>
       </select>
      </td>
                      <td>
       <select name="city"  class="form-control input-lg city"  id="city_1 data-id="1">
        <option value="">Select city</option>
       </select>
       </td>
               
     <td><input type="button" style="background-color:#a7cb00;" class="form-control input-lg addButton" value="add"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" style="background-color:blue;" class="form-control input-lg deleteButton" value="delete"/></td>
       </tr>
      <tr id="append_data">
  
      </td>
        </table>
 
     <input type="hidden" id="data_ids" value="2">
     </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I'm working on dependent dropdown list of country state and city and making clone of it.But on add everytime I click on first select box it clear the content of all previous one.Please help me on correcting this code.

Comment: Hi Mohit. Welcome to stack overflow. Please post relevant code.

Comment: You have a mistake on this line: id="country_1 data-id="1". You haven't finished the end quote for id. And this appears to be repeated throughout.